# Nginx rewrite '*/filename/playlist.m3u8' to '*/filename.mp4/index.m3u8' as redirect

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I'm trying to migrate over from Wowza and set-up VOD on Nginx on Debian through the help of Kaltura's nginx-vod-module, everything is working fine, apart from the existing VOD archive still req. to be accessible through the old URLs... so a rewrite rule is in order, but since it's a bad practice to do this, it should be a nginx redirect 'return 301 '.

The previously used Wowza URL format for files in the VOD archive was:

```
http://<server-address>:<rtmp-port>/vod/<file-name>/playlist.m3u8
```

The new URL format has to be:

```
http://<server-address>/vod/<file-name><file-extension>/index.m3u8
```

While I don't know much about rewrite rules, for now I've managed to put together a temp solution:

```
location ~ playlist.m3u8$ {
    rewrite ^(.*)/playlist.m3u8$ $1.mp4/index.m3u8;
}
```

But I don't know how would that translate into a working Redirect rule ('Return 301 ') or if it's possible to have one that would work universally without specifying each and every filename in the VOD folder.

---

While I'm at it, it kinda would be nice to have a simpler/shorter URL to access the newly added files.

```
http://<server-address>/vod/<file-name>.m3u8
```

The rewrite rule that should do that I think would be a combination of two rewrite rules, something like:

```
location ~ playlist.m3u8$ {
    rewrite ^(.*)/playlist.m3u8$ $1.mp4/index.m3u8;
}
location ~ index.m3u8$ {
    rewrite ^(.*).m3u8$ $1.mp4/index.m3u8;
}
```

But I'm worried it would target the URLs that have been rewritten and result in a HTTP error 404... suggestions to avoid that?

Comment: What is the source of `<file-extension>` in the replacement URL?  This is not clear.

Comment: I should have specified that in my case it's '*.mp4' but since it could be different file formats for different VOD set-ups (for example DASH instead of HLS), I left it rather vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
rewrite ^http://(.*?):\d+/vod/(.*?)/.*?\.(.*)$ http://$1/vod/$2.mp4/index.$3
```

## Regex101

Comment: The link alone is immensely helpful - I tried to find a tool like this but all my findings were of testers with too little info explaining what each and every part of a rewrite does or how much a rule covers. I'll test it out but from the looks of it, it seems to be spot on and solves my problem perfectly.

Comment: Shoved it under the /vod and so far it works as planned.

NGINX Vhost config snippet:
`location /vod {
 types {
  application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
  video/mp2t ts;
 }
 root <www-root-here>;

 #URL Rewrite for old Wowza VOD archive
 rewrite ^http://(.*?):\d+/vod/(.*?)/.*?\.(.*)$ http://$1/vod/$2.mp4/index.$3

 add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*';
 add_header Cache-Control "public, no-transform";

 vod hls;
 expires 7d;
}`